# android notification issue

Tags: android, notifications

I am working on an Android application.The app is like native sms application.I am facing a problem in notification part. In native app, they handle the notification in the following way.

1)if messages from an specific number ,then the click on the notification will lead to the chat page of the corresponding contact and the notification will clear.

2)if messages from the different number, then the click on the notification will lead to home page and notification won't clear.

I had done the first part and I don't have any idea to do the second part.
Is there any way to leave the notification part without clear and call an intent.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to add a flag:

```
 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

here a whole example:

```
 private static final int NOTIFICATION_EX = 0;
 private NotificationManager notificationManager;
```

...

in onCreate:

```
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



int icon = R.drawable.youricon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Sticky notification";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Sticky notification";
    CharSequence contentText = "...click here and it wont go away...";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, mainmenu.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
        0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, 
        contentText, contentIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_EX, notification);
```

the intent you can adjust to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create two different kind of notification, the first one you have already implemented, and the second one you can just copy the first one and check if the number is a different one use the second notification and set the flags to not clear `notification2.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;` on click with the HomeActivity in the `PendingIntent` which has `Intent`: